# Set appropriate initial height for custom task pane in VSTO Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in in which I create a custom task pane and I assign a usercontrol to it.

How can I set the initial height of the custom task pane in order to be device-independent, I mean,
that works independently of the screen resolution?

I have observed that if I set a fixed value for it, for example, ctp.Height = 130, it works on some screen resolutions but not in others, I mean, it seems height is not kept between different screen resolution. In lower screen resolutions, the height is bigger, and in higher screen resolutions, the height is smaller. Why is it happening? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Outlook first of all. Newest Outlook versions are DPI-aware, so the controls size can be changed depending on the DPI set per-monitor.

Another point is your configuration of the user control, how it is set up for auto-scaling.

Comment: My AutoScaleMode is set to Font.

Comment: If you set this property to `None` automatic scaling will be disabled.